# Export an Array of Objects AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am very new to development and I am trying to figure out the best way to convert a current export tool I wrote that exports a JSON object to now include a JSON object that has an array of objects on the inside. What I am referring to is the array of objects on profile:  I tried using .push() to put the objects into the array but I am lost.

**Ideal JSON object**

```
{
    "id":  "220a5f58-480e-45c3-8252-b3712d9e6c32",
    "name":  "hello",
    "profile":  [
        {
                "fullName":  "test",
                "displayName":  "test",
                "number":  "Unknown",
                "attributes":  {
                        "identifier":  true,
                        "categorical":  false,
                        "quantized":  false,
                        "relational":  false,
                        "ordinal":  false    
            }
        },
        {
            "fullName":  "test",
                "displayName":  "test",
                "number":  "Unknown",
                "attributes":  {
                        "identifier":  true,
                        "categorical":  false,
                        "quantized":  false,
                        "relational":  false,
                        "ordinal":  false   
            } 
        }
    ],
    "test": 12
}
```

**JS Code**

```
   // object.profile is a JSON object
   export.profile = [];
            angular.forEach(object.profile, function (value, key) {
              //export.profile[key] = {};
                export.push(profile[key] );
                export.profile[key].attributes = {};
                    export.profile[key].fullName = (value['original-name']);
                    export.profile[key].displayName = (value['display-name']);
                    export.profile[key].interpretation = (value['interpretation']['iName']);
                    export.profile[key].mainType = (value['main-type']);
```

Comment: have you gone though the doc ? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

Comment: Your keys doesn't match (display-name != displayName)

Comment: yes and yes I have

Comment: the keys dont need to match... as I am trying to figure out the profile array and how to add objects to it